# PHP: how can I call a function in a non-blocking fashion?

Tags: php, concurrency

I saw a couple of other question on the issue but not a clear answer.

I've a PHP file (must be PHP, cannot cron or other stuff) running from CLI where I must call the same function multiple time with different arguments:

```
doWork($param1);

doWork($param2);

doWork($param2);

function doWork($data)
{
//do stuff, write result to db
}
```

Each call makes HTTPs requests and parses the response. The operation can require up to a minute to complete. I must prevent the "convoy effect": each call must be executed without waiting for the previous one to complete.

PECL pthread is not an option due to server constraints.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do what you are looking for.

Instead of calling a function with its parameters, you have to call another cli php script in a nonblocking manner and put your function in that script.

This is your main script:

```
callDoWork($param1);
callDoWork($param2);
callDoWork($param3);

function callDoWork($param){
    $cmd = 'start "" /b php doWork.php '.$param;
    //if $param contains spaces or other special caracters for the command line,
    // you have to escape them.
    pclose(popen($cmd);
}
```

doWork.php would look like :

```
if(is_array($_SERVER['argv'])) $param = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
doWork($param);
function doWork($data)
{
    //do stuff, write result to db
}
```

[More information about argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

Answer (score 1):

How about adding `"> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"`

```
exec('php myFile.php  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

You can [check the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for more

Comment: I was hoping for something a little less hacky, but if nothing else comes up I'll go this way, thanks!